# Как подключиться к github?

Tags: git, repository, github

Работаю на ОС WIN7

1. Зарегистрировался на github.com
2. создал repository проекта на самом сайте
3. установил git( внутри есть файл git bash  и git gui)
4. создал папку для хранения проектов и папку проекта , вложенную в неё (git/spasalon-mvc)
5. Правой кнопкой мыши шлепнул по данной папке с одноименным названием моего проекта (выбрал git bash)
6. Выполнил следующие команды

   ```
   git config --global user.name "EVOSandru6" 
   git config --global user.email "EVOSduple@mail.ru"
   git init
   ```
7. `git clone git://github.com/EVOSandru6/spasalon-mvc.git`

Вышла ошибка - `Failed Connect to github.com:443`

Я так понял, что данная команда связывает папку локальную и repository на сайте github.com
До этого я в puttygen сформировал ssh ключ и добавил его в свой аккаунт. Не судите строго, я перелопатил habrahabr и stackoverflow, но там для меня не совсем понятно дана
информация.

В чем может быть причина ошибки?

Comment: а github клиент вам не нравится? с ним все гитхабовское из коробки работает.

Comment: Учочните, пожалуйсте, два момента:

1. из-под какой OS работаете?

2. не режет ли ваш провайдер соединения по 443 порту?

Answer (score 1):

`"git clone"` - создает локальную папку, и копирует туда репозиторий.
Если локальный репозиторий уже есть, то необходимо связать его с репой:

> git remote add <ссылка на репозиторий>

ssh ключи как я понимаю добавлены? И они у вас в ~/.ssh есть.

Comment: 1 . Я работаю на Win7 
2 . У меня  команда тоже сработала

Но не отрабатываются команды:

git add *
git commit -m "init"
git remote add origin https://github.com/EVOSandru6/spasalon-mvc.git
git push -u origin master

ssh ключи в ~/.ssh есть.